# Is it possible to place panel labels at the bottom in lattice?

Tags: r, lattice

Is it possible to place panel labels (i.e. 3gears, 4gears...) at the bottom instead of the top?

[image]

```
# Lattice Examples
library(lattice)
attach(mtcars)

# dotplot for each combination of two factors
dotplot(cyl.f~mpg|gear.f,
        main="Dotplot Plot by Number of Gears and Cylinders",
        xlab="Miles Per Gallon")
```

Thanks!

Comment: I thought this would be easy.  `?strip.default` seems like it ought to provide the answer.  But as far as I can see, it doesn't.  The latticeExtra package has a function `useOuterStrips` that does something different, but maybe looking at the source code for it would show how to put strips on the bottom.  I'm surprised it's not an easy option in Lattice.

Comment: I thought it was easy too but I can't find any information on how to do it. As far as I know, it is not possible to change the location of panels in GGPLOt so it may be the same case here. thanks

Comment: Well, you can put the panels on the side, and I think you can then choose either right or left.  But that uses arguments that are specifically designed for vertical panels.  I see nothing similar for horizontal panel placement.